# Date and time logic for an multi Time Zone Open/Close place system

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-5

I'm building a system where you got a lot of places, all around the world that need to show if they're open or close in real time.

The thing I've been debating on is how to do it, having never build this in any other project, I don't really know what is the best idea to achieve this goal.
I'd like to do it the right way so that I don't have to rebuild the entire date and time system later.

I use C# and .NET 5.0 for the API and Xamarin.Forms for the mobile app.

What I was thinking was:

- Either I use regular DateTime for the times and input, let's say, oh this place closes at 11pm, doesn't matter if it's in Sweden or UK, basically their Time Zone doesn't matter. Compare the place's closing time to the user's phone's internal region and time and if the user's phone says it's 11pm and the place closes at 11pm, display it as closed on their phone. I don't think it's a good idea because I think this data should be changed at the API level, not run a method for each user running the app, but I might be wrong.
- Or, I actually **create times related to their Time Zones** such as, I don't know what to use yet to be honest but, say DateTimeOffset or something and actually add the `TimeZone` as a property to the place's `Address`, then in the API compare it to the place's current time in its region and mark it as open or close for everyone in the world since it's on the server.

It might be a very simple question but I want to make sure I'm doing this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm building a system where you got a lot of places, all around the
> world that need to show if they're open or close in real time.

That's great.

> The thing I've been debating on is how to do it, having never build
> this in any other project, I don't really know what is the best idea
> to achieve this goal. I'd like to do it the right way so that I don't
> have to rebuild the entire date and time system later.

Exactly, you don't need to reinvent the wheel. There a lot of example on the internet that you can use for that. Just be careful to create your system design based on your requirements.

> Either I use regular DateTime for the times and input, let's say, oh
> this place closes at 11pm, doesn't matter if it's in Sweden or UK,
> basically their Time Zone doesn't matter. Compare the place's closing
> time to the user's phone's internal region and time and if the user's
> phone says it's 11pm and the place closes at 11pm, display it as
> closed on their phone. I don't think it's a good idea because I think
> this data should be changed at the API level, not run a method for
> each user running the app, but I might be wrong.

Yes, that's *not* a great idea. Nowadays, actually smart phones are quite smart to update their local time when they have internet connection but "region" subject is still under users control. That's why the subject of "local time" will be always depends on user regions, phones time zone system and how up to date of "that" system. For example, you can still live in Turkey but you "can" set your region settings for another country, like Germany. In that case, "the place where user lives" and "region settings on the phone" matters. My 11:00PM can be *easily* different than your 11:00PM.

One of the solutions can be taking location information on the phone and calculating user's time zone and inform and/or compare phone's time.

A nice guy named [Matt Johnson-Pint](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634824/matt-johnson-pint) created 2 useful library for that. [GeoTimeZone](https://github.com/mj1856/GeoTimeZone) and [TimeZoneConverter](https://github.com/mj1856/TimeZoneConverter). You can find the time zone information of the user for longitude and latitude easily.

For example;

```
string tzIana = TimeZoneLookup.GetTimeZone(lat, lng).Result;
TimeZoneInfo tzInfo = TZConvert.GetTimeZoneInfo(tzIana);
DateTimeOffset convertedTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, tzInfo);
```

Remember, time zones matters!

> Or, I actually create times related to their Time Zones such as, I
> don't know what to use yet to be honest but, say DateTimeOffset or
> something and actually add the TimeZone as a property to the place's
> Address, then in the API compare it to the place's current time in its
> region and mark it as open or close for everyone in the world since
> it's on the server.

Yes, that sounds more logical.

> Please let me know how I should do it and also explain how I should
> implement it in detail

Sorry, Stack Overflow is for *specific* programming problems and this part of your question does not meet the standart of [asking a proper question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/) a few times before asking more questions.

Comment: Thank you so much Soner ! Thank you for letting me know which way is best. I also had a question about that, after implementing the timezone conversion, should I add a property such as `bool IsOpen` to the `Hours` table and have a calculation such as if local timezone of the place is BETWEEN open time and close time, mark it as open, else, mark it as closed ?